# LLDB Step Multiple Instructions?

Tags: macos, debugging, assembly, gdb, lldb

In GDB it is possible to step multiple instructions with a single command. After much searching, it does not appear to be possible to do the same in LLDB.

For example, in GDB, if you enter `si 5`, you will step forward 5 instructions. However, doing the same in LLDB results in:

> error: Thread index 5 is out of range (valid values are 0 - 1).

In GDB running `si` with an integer defines how many instructions to step, but in LLDB it defines which thread to step forward 1 instruction.

Is there any way to step forward multiple instructions in LLDB as can be done in GDB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an enhancement that is on our queue, but somehow never makes it to the top.  I added a --count option to step-inst & step-next-inst as my lunch time hack.  It's in TOT lldb, can't say when it will make it into an official Apple release.

Answer (score 3):

If you're stuck on an older version of LLDB and don't have the feature which was implemented after this question was asked, or simply want to automate repeating any arbitrary commands, here is a quick-and-dirty way of scripting multiple commands which can be entered easily from the interactive LLDB python prompt:

```
lldb.debugger.SetAsync(False)
for _ in range(3): lldb.debugger.HandleCommand('si')
```

The above will make the API synchronous, so that each command will complete before running the next, and then loop executing commands (3 times in this example).

To access this prompt, enter the `script` command at the LLDB prompt, then Python away.

```
(lldb) script
```